# Javascript array formatting error from php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array, such as this:

`[['jkjhkfhkjh jkj jkjhk', '54.324705', '-2.749629', '189', 1, 1, 0, 0, 'Test two', '2 ', '10+', 'http://xx.co.uk/xx/?post_type=listings&amp;p=189', '<img width="160" height="85" src="http://www.xx.com/manage/wp-content/uploads/wheelbase.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="wheelbase" title="wheelbase">', '189'],['fghfghfgh &nbsp;fghfg hf dfh dfh', '54.323174', '-2.744554', '188', 1, 1, 0, 0, 'Test', '2 ', '10+', 'http://xx/xx/?post_type=listings&amp;p=188', '<img width="160" height="85" src="http://www.xx.com/manage/wp-content/uploads/wheelbase.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="wheelbase" title="wheelbase">', '188']];`

I get the data using php:

```
echo "[";
  for ($i=0; $i < count($json); $i++) { 
    echo "['" . $json[$i]["content"] . "', '". $json[$i]["lat"] . "', '" . $json[$i]["long"] . "', '" . $json[$i]["id"] . "', 1, 1, 0, 0, '" . $json[$i]["title"] . "', '2 ', '10+', '" . $json[$i]["link"] . "', '<img width=\"160\" height=\"85\" src=\"http://www.xx.com/manage/wp-content/uploads/wheelbase.jpg\" class=\"attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image\" alt=\"wheelbase\" title=\"wheelbase\" />', '" . $json[$i]["id"] . "'],";
  }   
  echo "]";
```

(I called a variable `$json` , ignore the fact i called it that, it is not json)

So I echo these out into a div which will be hidden. Then to pick it up in javascript I try this:

`var locations = $('#listingsarray').html();`

which seems to translate fine into the console, but it is coming in as text rather than as an array. How can I turn this into an array?

Comment: How are you retrieving the JSON?

Comment: HTML doesn't support arrays, so of course it's text ?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary im just echoing out some data in the format of a javascript array

Comment: @adeneo yeah im unsure how to translate it. I tried .text() but again, its not an array. How can I bring it into my js as an array?

Comment: Show the line you're echoing.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but isn't it obvious that `.html()` or `.text()` return strings? After all, HTML *is* text.

Comment: You are taking a jsonish string placing it into an html context as text then you want to interpret it as a javascript array? May I ask why you are doing all of this?

Comment: @Orangepill to be iterated through in javascript putting pins on a map

Comment: @JoshBoothe but... why are you placing it in the html to begin with? there's far better ways to get data from php to javascript. And, the array you're generating isn't valid JSON, therefore that cuts out a lot of possibilities (such as getting the data with ajax)

Comment: @KevinB yeah im aware that how im doing it is a really sloppy (and invalid) method, which is why I came here to try learn how to pass a variable in the correct datatype over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need to build a valid json representation of an array, the technique you are using is resulting in invalid syntax. This Should work out better for you.

```
$data = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($json); $i++) { 
  $data[] =  array(
                  $json[$i]["content"],
                  $json[$i]["lat"],
                  $json[$i]["long"],
                  $json[$i]["id"],
                  1,
                  1,
                  0,
                  0,
                  $json[$i]["title"],
                  '2',
                  '10+',
                  $json[$i]["link"],
                  '<img width=\"160\" height=\"85\" src=\"http://www.xx.com/manage/wp-content/uploads/wheelbase.jpg\" class=\"attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image\" alt=\"wheelbase\" title=\"wheelbase\" />',
                  $json[$i]["id"]
              );
}
$jsonString = json_encode($data);
```

Then if you want to put it into a json context you can simply do this

```
<script>var jsonArray = <?= $jsonString ?>;</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this. I dont think it is parsing as an array still, in the console it is coming out as being just a single dimentional array without the square brackets `[]` so its just like `value,value,value` and so on (obviously replace value with the actual value expected. I think it is getting there however!

Comment: @JoshBoothe Make sure you are __NOT__ putting quotes around the echo like `<script>var jsonArray = '<?= $jsonString ?>';</script>` it should be `<script>var jsonArray = <?= $jsonString ?>;</script>`

Comment: @JoshBoothe and double check how you are building the $data variable... you should be building an array of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse` to parse the string into JSON, but keep in mind that it won't be valid. You'd be much better off doing this:

```
echo json_encode(array_map("array_values",$json));
```

This assumes that the keys are in the order "content", "lat", "long"... and that there are no other keys. If this is not the case, you'll need to iterate through the array to make sure everything's right, then use `json_encode`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're outputting this on page load, try this instead:

```
echo "<script>var locations = [";
for ($i=0; $i < count($json); $i++) { 
  //...
}   
echo "]</script>";
```

Then your javascript will have direct access to the `locations` variable and the array without translating or `eval`ing it.

Though I would certainly look into using `json_encode`, as the libraries are much better at handling edge cases and the code is much cleaner.